# How can I change the cursor's appearance based on the cursor's location?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change my cursor appearance to a left arrow when on the left half of my screen and a right arrow when on the right half of the screen. Specifically, wondering how to do this with Javascript. Something that looks like [this](https://shewasonly.co.uk/).

Tried doing it based on mouse location as well as overall page width (ie. if x-mouselocation > page width: change to right cursor). But couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so change class on mouse move? Or just change the cursor based on element hover... Is your page laid out in columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any animations then you can simply do this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.image {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/cUpp1gAEtiU/");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  
  /*  This is important  */
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/314qF.png"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The web site you referenced basically has a set of nested divs. The inner most div is simply displaying an image as the mouse hovers over each side.

You could setup something similar

```css
    .left,
    .right {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      height: 85%;
      width: 51vw;
      cursor: none!important;
      .left .inner,
      .right .inner {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='left'>
      <div class='inner'>
        <img src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/61c9a64205be24caa4a33a4725a3b6dc6785d44d/0df5b/img/icons/arrow-left.svg" style="left: 395px; top: 369.062px;">
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Full disclosure: The style and idea for this was taken directly from https://shewasonly.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I used JS to check which side of the page the mouse is on, then applied classes to an element on both cases.

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  // Getting the width of the body and dividing it by 2
  const width = +getComputedStyle(document.body).width.slice(0, -2) / 2;

  wrap.classList.remove('mouse-left', 'mouse-right'); // Removing the mouse classes
  wrap.classList.toggle('mouse-left', e.pageX <= width); // Toggling mouse-left class if mouse position on the left
  wrap.classList.toggle('mouse-right', e.pageX > width); // Toggling mouse-right if mouse position on the right
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #8360c3 49.9%, #2ebf91 50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mouse-right {
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  width='40' height='48' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:24px;'><text y='50%'></text></svg>") 16 0, auto;
}

.mouse-left {
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  width='40' height='48' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:24px;'><text y='50%'></text></svg>") 16 0, auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div>
```